# Duplicate fields on a form

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

Is there a way to repeat fields in the Craft Formbuilder (FreeForm)?

I’m working on a form on which I want to be able to have multiple names/addresses.

Rather than add a new field every time (name 1, name 2, etc.), is there a way to simply copy fields?

Answer (score 1):

Not with Freeform - the fields can only be used once in each form, similar to how fields are used in native Craft elements.

I believe [Formie](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/formie/features) allows you to re-use fields.